# s3 data lake and Athena - How to conclude the final state

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena, data-lake

We have devices that can have different sorts of alerts. Alerts can be generated over a period of time so it is time series data.

So let's say:

12:00: Device1 is in the connection alarm stage

12:02: Device alarm acknowledged

12:09: Device alarm off

Now, in reports for devices we will have to say:

when and for how long was device1 in the alarms stage?

-> How should this be stored/queried efficiently from the S3 data lake? I wondering if I should have data partitioned by YYY/MM/DD/ for this. If yes, let's say the user requested the report for 2022-08-01-2022-08-02, and the device alarm was acknowledged on 2022-08-3 and the device alarm had started on 2022-07-31. How would an Athena query find that?

-> If it should not be partitioned by timestamp, I'd still like to know the best way to get information about a device stage for the requested period without missing information for the situations similar to shared above.

Comment: I'm not sure I would recommend data lake for this purpose. it's possible but you'll have to scan quite a lot of data especially if the "acknowledgment" is not limited by some reasonable time. - can you incorporate an additional database / service for these reporting purposes?

Comment: We have this data stored in Dynamo but we have been trying to run our reporting from S3 @TomSlabbaert . This data in dynamo for every alarm is a single record with alarm on, alarm off and alarm ack time.

Comment: are there some restrictions on the reporting? is it going to be only last 24h?, also is there a max time you can assume till ack?. the reason this is relevant is that for historical reporting s3 is going to be very expensive without any assumptions

Comment: @TomSlabbaert I see. If we were to stream the changes on every data to alarm record in Dynamo to S3, How should the updates be handled? What should happen to the old records?